# Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /script.php on line 9633

Tags: php

The following code is generating these messages:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /script.php on line 9633
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /script.php on line 9633
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /script.php on line 9633
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in /script.php on line 9633
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in /script.php on line 9633
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 13 in /script.php on line 9633
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 15 in /script.php on line 9633
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 15 in /script.php on line 9633

The truth is that the script works for me but this "error" worries me... Anybody can help me please?

```
// fotos
$fotos = $row['guids_fotos'];
$fotos2 = explode('_',$fotos);
$imagenes = $fotos2[1].','.$fotos2[3].','.$fotos2[5].','.$fotos2[7].','.$fotos2[9].','.$fotos2[11].','.$fotos2[13].','.$fotos2[15];
```

Answer (score 2):

inside your $fotos2 variable wich is an array; you should have 1 or maybe 2 cells, wich mean your variable $foto only contain 1 or 2 "_" character. I think your separator is not "_", if you can provide us the result of var_dump($fotos) it will be usefull

Comment: Thank you very much, I will send you var_dump ($ photos) and var_dump ($ images);
The case is as follows: From Table guids_fotos I have to remove the 2 value of each "batch" of images, and then separate them by commas.

Because the maximum length of characters I can not post it here.

Comment: OK, so assuming you are using mysql_fetch_row() function to get your $row['guids_fotos'], you variable $fotos is an array, but explode normally take a string into argument and transform it in an array, for example here the string "123_456_789" will return an array("123","456","789"). I don't get what you want to do by computing only odd indexes. Can you describe more the structure of the string you want in the end, and what you have at the beginning...

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help.
guids_fotos structure is as follows: (I write in the next post.)
Each value is separated by comma are 3 photos. Small, medium and large sizes each is separated by "_".
I need to get the middle (median) is why I use the odd. Until 8 photos
I am currently working properly but I get the error.
Sorry my translation. I use Google translator. : (

Comment: guids_fotos structure     {84375F7A-1CB1-4A01-A79F-C519F3063AA3}_{22BE3542-FBAB-4E26-ADB1-AE4712011BFE}_{CE3F81E4-A562-4EFB-B989-1BD5CF815163},{B26A29A2-6D1A-44C6-A903-62F2D71ACA62}_{61AF803A-6BCB-428B-83B4-B6071CD5C47C}_{20DD8363-CDBC-4D2D-9217-930F698146A5},{BB6CD854-279E-4441-B3BD-F82C7DD417B9}_{BD356E47-0E54-406A-B501-F380F50F450D}_{ABD1F0F1-E18D-4C07-8CBE-4918C947DA8F}

Comment: The probleme may be that your SQL query didn't return what you expect so first check your query, then check the inside of $fotos variable and then check again $fotos2, you can use var_dump() to help you understanding where the problem is

Comment: Ok
thank you very much.
I'll look.

Comment: Hello again friend.
I know why the problem. Some  guids_fotos records just there are 3 or 4 photos and that is why the error message.
How I can do to avoid that error message appears?.
The truth is that not much programming.

Comment: you can check the size of the array with the function count, for example: `if (count($fotos2) == 3){ /* Compute the 3 photos */}`

Comment: Hello friend, Please can you tell me...
in my case, where I have to put "if (count($fotos2) == 3)"? ...

Comment: This is the number of photos in your array ... in this case you will only have access to $fotos2[0], $fotos2[1] and $fotos2[2]. So $imagenes = $fotos2[1] is the only thing acceptable i guess